# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer distintos niveles de un Dictionary?

Tags: c#

Estuve leyendo mucha documentacion de como recorrer un Dictionary con un foreach, pero no termino de entender cómo puedo recorrer los niveles que tiene
Por ejemplo:

Tengo el Diccionary paramateros, le agrego valores string y de objeto, con `.Add()`, y a uno de ellos le agrego un nivel llamado "item".

Por lo que entiendo, con el `Foreach(KeyValueaPair<>)` es para recorrer los Dictionary. Necesito usar otro `foreach(KeyValuePair<>)` para poder recorrer el segundo nivel?

Por ejemplo, quiero que "param"  obtenga el valor del elemento que trae Posnr

```
            IDictionary<string, object> parametros = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            parametros.Add("Customerid", zwCustomer.Customerid); // valor debe ser un objeto en el cual implemente el metodo set y get ...
            parametros.Add("PedidoCli", zwCustomer.PedidoCli);
            parametros.Add("PedidoSap", zwCustomer.PedidoSap);

            //para agregar niveles un nuevo objeto diccionario
            parametros.Add("TFacturaMat", new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                {
                    "item", new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        {"Vbeln", zfacturaMats.Vbeln},
                        {"Posnr", zfacturaMats.Posnr},
                        {"Matnr", zfacturaMats.Matnr},
                    }
                },
            });

           foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> item in parametros)
           {
                param = $"{item.Key} : {item.Value}";
           }
```

Comment: Necesito usar otro foreach(KeyValuePair<>) para poder recorrer el segundo nivel? si.

Comment: Y sería  foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> item in parametros){  foreach(KeyValuePair<string, object> item2 in parametros){ }} ?

Comment: lo probaste?? igual mandar un objeto, a un diccionario, suena muyyyyyyyyy raro...

Comment: Mando un objeto al diccionario porque sería lo que me devuelva el Soap, primero quiero probarlo asi y sino en vez de objeto mando un string. Lo que quiero  es saber si haciendo los foreach, me trae bien los datos, por lo que todavía no pude probarlo

Comment: Sigo investigando para saber si está bien lo que estoy haciendo.

Comment: entonces no entiendo que estas preguntando... si no podes probarlo, cual seria el problema?

Comment: El problema es que no sabía cómo recorrer los niveles de un Dictionary con un foreach, por ejemplo como recorrer el elemento "item", que está dentro de "TFacturaMat". No enconté algun documento o video que me lo pueda explicar.

Comment: por lo que decis, no deja de ser un diccionario dentro de otro diccionario.. por lo tanto, recorrer cualquiera es lo mismo.. Igual, deberias hacer un programa de prueba y probarlo...

Comment: Si, es lo que tengo pensado hacer. Muchas gracias por la ayuda